# Update outer page from canvas app

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, canvas, canvas-app

I have several canvas apps implemented through lightning components on a lightning record page.  The lightning page also contains a highlights panel and other panels that are native to lightning.

When data is updated by the canvas app, I would like for the outer page components (the highlights panel, etc) to refresh with the latest data.  For example, one of the fields in the highlights panel shows the total value of a Quote - when the canvas app adds line items to the quote, I would like the value in the highlights panel to update to reflect the changes.  Right now, the user has to refresh the whole page in order to get the panel to update.

I can fire an event from the canvas app just fine - there is tons of documentation on how to do that - but there's no documentation I can find on actually subscribing to that event in the components' controllers in order to fire `force:refreshView`.  I'm not even sure if that's the right approach.  Has anyone managed to do something like this and if so, how?